# Particle system rendered as object has weird shadow issues in Cycles, that is fixed when using children or random scale

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, shadows

I'm using particle system to distribute feather objects on a bird body. When I naively set it up and try to render it with Cycles, there is some of the objects shadows are not realistic (many of the feathers are in the dark although they should not be). Eevee render looks OK. The material on the feathers is a relatively simple Principled BSDF with alpha, roughness, and color channels textured.

[image: wrong shadows]

I've found a few workarounds: I can either use interpolated children and set the amount to 1, resulting in good shadows:
[image: ok shadows when using children]
or I can add something about 0.2 scale randomness - lower amounts do help the issue but they don't remedy it completely. Note that adjusting only the scale does not help at all.
[image: ok shadows when using scale randomness]

However, I still don't understand the underlying issue. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently with rendering grass using particle systems. what worked for me was increasing the number of light bounces in the light paths tab. Increasing the transparent bounces helped the most but try playing with the other settings too.